# Print out the words of a line in reverse order through recursion

Tags: c++

I'm trying not to use any storage containers. I don't know if it's even possible. Here is what I have so far. (I'm getting a segmentation fault).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void foo(string s)
{
    size_t pos;
    pos = s.find(' ');
    if(pos == string::npos)
        return;
    foo(s.erase(0, pos));
    cout << s.substr(0, pos) << " ";
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I know there's probably many things wrong with this code. So rip away. I'm eager to learn. I'm trying to imitate a post order print as you would do in a reverse print of a singly linked list. Thanks.

EDIT:
An example:
"You are amazing" becomes "amazing are You"

Comment: Why don't you push the substrings of the sentence in a stack and print them after popping?

Comment: @codePassion `I'm trying not to use any storage containers`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segfault is a stack overflow.

`foo( "hello world" )` erases everything up to the first space (`" world"`) and recurses.

`foo( " world" )` erases everything up to the first space (`" world"`) and recurses.

`foo( " world" )`... you get the idea.

Also, once you called `foo( s.erase( 0, pos ) )`, trying to print `s.substr( 0, pos )` after the recursion returns does not make sense. You need to save the substring somewhere before you erase it, so you still have it to print afterwards.

```
void foo(string s)
{
    size_t pos = s.find(' ');            // declare-and-use in one line
    string out = s.substr( 0, pos );     // saving the substring
    if ( pos != string::npos )
    {
        foo( s.erase( 0, pos + 1 ) );    // recurse, skipping the space...
        cout << " ";                     // ...but *print* the space
    }
    cout << out;                         // print the saved substring
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your recursion continues until you run out of memory.
Pay attention to this line:

```
if(pos == string::npos)
```

when your erase the substring you don't erase the white space so in the next recursion s.find returns `pos = 0` which means that your recursion never ends.

Here is a code that works. Also note that I added a level variable to be able to control the behaviour on the first level (in this case add a `endl`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void foo(string s, int l)
{
    size_t pos;
    pos = s.find(' ');
    if(pos == string::npos){
        cout << s << " ";
        return;
    }

    string temp = s.substr(0, pos);
    foo(s.erase(0, pos+1),l+1);
    cout << temp << " ";
    if(l == 0)
        cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello world", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An approach to recursion, which *may* allow your compiler to transform automatically to iteration, is to accumulate the result in the function arguments.  This will be familiar if you've written recursive functions in any of the Lisp family of languages:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse_words(const std::string& s, const std::string& o = {})
{
    using std::string;
    const auto npos = string::npos;

    static const string whitespace(" \n\r\t");
    // find start and end of the first whitespace block
    auto start = s.find_first_of(whitespace);
    if (start == npos)
        return s + o;
    auto end = s.find_first_not_of(whitespace, start);
    if (end == npos)
        return s + o;
    auto word = s.substr(0, start);
    auto space = s.substr(start, end-start);
    auto rest = s.substr(end);
    return reverse_words(rest, space + word + o);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << reverse_words("hello to all the world") << std::endl;
    std::cout << reverse_words("  a more   difficult\n testcase   ") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is in adding `1` to `pos` in the erase statement.
So try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void foo(string s)
{
    size_t pos;
    pos = s.find(' ');
    if(pos == string::npos)
    {
        cout << s << " ";
        return;
    }
    string out = s.substr(0, pos);
    foo(s.erase(0, pos+1));
    cout << out << " ";
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello world");
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you could use a `char*` instead of a `std::string`, then you do not need to make a temp variable. Try it [online](http://ideone.com/46pmal).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void foo(char* s)
{
    char* next = std::strchr(s, ' ');
    if(next != nullptr)
    {
        foo(next + 1);
        *next = 0;
    }
    std::cout << s << " ";
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "You are amazing";
    foo(s);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make a brief example by using standard algorithms. I also handles more kinds of spaces than just standard whitespace (tabs for instance).

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print_reverse(string words) {
  // Termination condition
  if(words.empty())
    return;

  auto predicate = (int(*)(int))isspace;
  auto sit = begin(words);
  auto wit = find_if_not(sit, end(words), predicate);
  auto nit = find_if    (wit, end(words), predicate);

  print_reverse(string(nit, end(words)));
  //      word                spaces
  cout << string(wit, nit) << string(sit, wit);
}

int main() {
  string line;
  getline(cin, line);
  print_reverse(line);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Here is an example run:

```bash
$ ./print-out-the-words-of-a-line-in-reverse-order-through-recursion                         
You     are amazing                                                                          
amazing are     You
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not doing anything with the last word and you're not doing anything with the remaining chunk.

If you have a recursive reverse printer, you'll want something like this (pseudocode):

```
def recursive-reverse(string) {
  pos = string.find-last(" ");
  if pos doesn't exist {
    print string;
    return;
  } else {
    print string.create-substring(pos+1, string.end);
    recursive-reverse(string.create-substring(0, pos));
  }
}
```

To implement this in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void recursive_reverse(std::string &s) {
  // find the last space
  size_t pos = s.find_last_of(" ");
  // base case - there's no space
  if(pos == std::string::npos) {
    // print only word in the string
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    // end of recursion
    return;
  } else {
    // grab everything after the space
    std::string substring = s.substr(pos+1);
    // print it
    std::cout << substring << std::endl;
    // grab everything before the space
    std::string rest = s.substr(0, pos);
    // recursive call on everything before the space
    recursive_reverse(rest);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string s("Hello World!");
  recursive_reverse(s);
  return 0;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/4dxRkS)